# Linux command to search files using pipes

Tags: text-processing, logs, pipe, syslog

**Problem:** I need to find the 5 services that have produced most logging messages in files `/var/log/syslog` and `/var/log/syslog.1`.

- `tr` - to remove process numbers, so that all processes seem equal.
- `cut` - to show only the name of the process.

Also, I think I need to use `uniq`, `sort` and `head` commands.

Comment: Smells like homework. What have you tried?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and i) show us what you've tried so far and what is giving you trouble so we don't repeat things you already know; ii) show us an example of your input files and your desired output and iii) explain why you need to use those commands specifically. Is that a requirement? Why? Why not use anything that works?

Answer (score 2):

The service name is available in column five in the syslog logfile (as found on an Ubuntu machine with default syslog setup).  It is usually listed as `servicename[pid]:`, for example `CRON[1233]:` or `ntpd[9283]:` etc.

To get the fifth field:

```
awk '{ print $5 }' /var/log/syslog
```

To delete everything from that field, from the `[` onwards:

```
awk '{ sub("[[].*", "", $5); print $5 }' /var/log/syslog
```

Now you'll get a list like

```
dhclient
dhclient
dhclient
CRON
ntpd
CRON
CRON
ntpd
```

Now you just have to sort these and count them, and retain the top ones:

```
awk '{ sub("[[].*", "", $5); print $5 }' /var/log/syslog |
sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | head -n 5
```

This may output something like

```
 27 dhclient
 23 CRON
 13 ntpd
```

(only three services on this particular machine).

To remove the numbers, filter that through `awk '{ print $2 }'`.

---

You could use `tr` and `cut` as well, but these are slightly too "simple" tools for this job IMHO. `cut` in particular needs to know *exactly* how many delimiter characters to cut by, so if a column is delimited by more than a single space character, `cut` needs to take that into account.

Comment: `cut -d ' ' -f 5` would not work for logs on the 1st to 9th day of the month. That's where you'd need to use `tr -s ' '`

Comment: Note that not all syslog lines include a `[pid]`.

Answer (score 1):

`tr` transliterates characters indiscriminately, it's not really appropriate here `tr -d 0-9` would remove all decimal digits including those in the service names. It can be useful though to squeeze sequences of delimiters into one so `cut` can be used.

What you need is locate the column that contains the service name and extract the service name from it.

Which column it is will depend on how syslog has been configured, in particular when it comes to the timestamp formatting.

You can see things like:

```
2018-03-13T07:17:01.506581-07:00 host CRON[26456]: (root) CMD (...)
```

Where the service name is in the third column or:

```
Mar 14 00:35:01 host CRON[19234]: (root) CMD (...)
```

Where it's in the fifth column.

In that latter format, there can be either 1 or 2 spaces in between the month and day columns (that's where you'd use `tr -s ' '` if you wanted to use `cut` on it). Also note that the `[pid]` part is not guaranteed to be there (like for kernel logs or logs received over the network (those latter ones may not even have a "service" column)).

A method that would work for those two different formats, with GNU grep or compatible built with PCRE support would be:

```
grep -Po '^.{7}\S+ \S+ \K[^\s:[]+' /var/log/syslog |
  sort |
  uniq -c |
  sort -rn |
  head -n 5
```

That is skip the first 7 characters and all the non-spacing ones after that (which would cover the timestamp for both formats) and an extra column (`\S+` in between two spaces: the host name) and then match on the sequence of characters other than spacing, colon and `]` after that (`\K` marking the start of the matched portion).

A regex-based approach, here using the more feature-rich perl-like ones, gives you a lot more flexibility. The same expressed with `cut` would be:

```
</var/log/syslog cut -c 8- |
  cut -d ' ' -f3 |
  cut -d : -f 1 |
  cut -d '[' -f 1 |
  sort |
  uniq -c |
  sort -rn |
  head -n 5
```